# What’s the best way to view all my iCloud Documents without opening different apps?

Tags: data-synchronization, macos, iwork, icloud

I frequently have to copy over documents to and fro iCloud and my Desktop. It’s really tedious to open each iWork app, search through the list, copy my file and repeat. Is it possible to view all my files at once or at least in a single window?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I use Cloud Mate which shows all iCloud documents from all Apps (including iOS ones). Only been using it for a couple of days, but it's very simple and does exactly what it says it does:

http://www.rwe-uk.com/app/cloud-mate

Comment: Wow! There should be more apps like that! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

You could use [the iCloud website](https://www.icloud.com/) to manage that.
On the iWork section, you can switch between documents types using tabs on the top :

[image: iCloud.com tabs]

With the settings button on the right, you can upload document and by clicking on a document, you can download it on your computer.
You still need to switch between documents type but you use only one app : your browser.

Comment: Wow! I really didn’t know that! I thought it was only for iOS but didn’t realise that now OS X documents also work.

Comment: This will only work for iWork documents, not for other applications using iCloud.

Answer (score 0):

Tag each file with a subject name and they will be sorted in the tag section of the Finder sidebar, irrespective of the app they use.

(I only use the tag colours to show them up)

eg.

[image: Tag based file system]